# Node.js - Server crashes when started on startup, doesn't crash when manually started

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I am running Node.js and Socket.io for online chat.
I have created a file in:

```
/etc/init/example.conf
```

it has two lines:

```
start on startup
exec forever start /var/www/example.com/html/server.js //location of server file.
```

Whenever I start file upload in chat application, it crashes but instantly restarts.

Whenever I kill node process though, and start it manually - it works fine.

I also can't get any logs or anything from terminal as when it's auto started - it doesn't print me anything to terminal.

I am still new to Node.js and Linux in general.
Node.js is running on Express + Jade.

How do I determine specific cause?

Comment: @Transcendence I just read about tail method and I was able to attach my terminal to auto started process. I found error

Comment: @arleitiss if you found the solution to your problem could you post it as answer, preferably with some description of how you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, after a bit of searching around I found out about tail command.

My issue was a bit harder to trace because Node.js was a process started by autostart so when I launched terminal and connected to server, process was just running in background basically and I wouldn't get any output (including exception messages).

Anyway, solution that worked for me was:

I typed

```
ps aux | grep node //to find PID of node process
```

then I went to following directory

```
cd /proc/[pid of running node service]/fd
```

In fd directory there are few objects you can get output from but if you want to attach and listen to servers output including uncaught exceptions, you need 1.
So:

```
tail -f 1
```

that way I was able to cause website to crash and see the output.